# Critique: Modified template for a greeting card service

Tags: critique, website-templates

I'm modifying a [template](http://html5up.net/escape-velocity) to suit my own needs.  While I've been fairly successful overall, I've been struggling with the pricing section.

Specifically:

- I picked the colors because they were complimentary to the background, but they don't seem to be readable.  What process can I use to pick colors that blend well, but allow easy readability?
- The plan titles seem to be too small.  Should I increase their size?
- Originally, the box sizes were [tiered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83FOS.png) to draw the eye to the biggest plan.  Is there some way to allow easy comparison (i.e. the text of different plans on the same horizontal level) while still allowing the tiers?

I'm still new to the design side of things, so please explain more advanced terms in your answer.  Comments as to how I can improve the general look of things are also welcome.

[image: Site]

(Based off of [Escape Velocity](http://html5up.net/escape-velocity))

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to list some points as bullets, not to be blunt but so I don't end up writing a huge essay here. Take them all with a grain of salt, its your project after all. I work in Marketing so some of this will be tips from a Marketing perspective and touching on copy:

- Drop Facebook to its own line and centered in the "Sign up with Facebook" button will then allow the buttons as a whole to look better aligned.
- Switch "What is Card Minion?" and "Never forget to send a birthday card again" or reword one or both. Right now its odd because the answer to the question is not the Never... the answer is Monthly batches
- "Monthly batches of cards..." should add some descriptor in front of cards. It will help the single word on the second line and can help both communicate what kind of cards and your brand trust. "Monthly batches of specialty cards.." "birthday cards" "customized cards"
- Instead of saying "We ship to you to add.." switch "add" with "personalize" probably worth removing either "just" "simple" or both.
- "Pricing" is a missed opportunity to build that trust you're wanting. Think you could change it to "Up front pricing" or "Friendly pricing" or some other adjective.
- The words "Basic" "Friends" and "Everyone" doesn't have the same feel as the rest of the site. For one thing the space between them and their "box" is much smaller spacing then anything else on the site. Increase the space so they match something else on the site like the heading of the endorsements to the actual endorsements.
- The colors are off, maybe keep it with the grey/blue or a thin white
  outline. Doesn't look right currently to me.
- The padding as `rlemon` mentioned in comment should match top and bottom
- They look slightly wider then the testimonial photos
- "Basic, Friends, Everyone Else" is odd word choices. You've got two personified and then Basic. If you have the power to change the naming I'd look into doing so.

I'd probably fix the padding on pricing, get rid of the colors for a simple white outline, change the naming, and add a simple icon like you have on the other parts.

I like the feel overall, hope this helps you take it to the next level!

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 I'll see about making some changes to reflect your edit when I have time. Also meant to say be sure to do A/B Testing as well particularly on phrasing and changes to your pricing boxes. See what phrasing and design leads to the most conversions.